# How to make a fixed name for an outgoing call in CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I'm creating an outgoing one like this and I want to make a fixed name to display in calls, but for some reason remoteAddress is substituted there anyway(

```
func outgoingCall(remoteAddress: String) {
        mProviderDelegate.incomingCallUUID = UUID()
        let handle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: remoteAddress)
        let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call:  mProviderDelegate.incomingCallUUID, handle: handle)
        startCallAction.contactIdentifier = "Name"
        startCallAction.isVideo = false

        let transaction = CXTransaction()
        transaction.addAction(startCallAction)

        mProviderDelegate.mCallController.request(transaction) { error in
            if let error = error {
            } else {
               
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering seems to be related to how CallKit displays the calling name and address. When you create an outgoing call using CallKit, the `CXHandle` determines the name or number displayed to the user.

In the given code, you're setting the `CXHandle` value to `remoteAddress`, which means that the `remoteAddress` will be displayed. The `contactIdentifier` you've set using `startCallAction.contactIdentifier = "Name"` is typically used for caller identification but doesn't overwrite the display value set by the `CXHandle`.

### Solution

To display a fixed name in outgoing calls, you should set the `CXHandle`'s value to that name:

```swift
let handle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Name")
```

### Additional Information

And if you still need to keep track of the **remoteAddress**, you might consider other ways to store or manage it, separate from the UI-related components of CallKit.

Remember, though, that using a generic handle type with a name might not always make sense, especially if you're dialing a number. If you're working with actual phone numbers, you might want to reevaluate this approach. The goal is to ensure clarity for the user, so they know who they are calling. If you're working with a VOIP service or some other kind of non-traditional phone service where "Name" makes sense as an address, then this approach should be okay.